# How can i add mouse hover effect on the conditioned background rows according to php result

Tags: javascript, html

`<?php if($result["staff_follow"]== 'By Party'&& $result["Status"]== 'PENDING'): ?>  style="background-color:#E99E3E;`

the below feiled is not working.
*"onmouseover="this.bgColor='litegreen'" onmouseout="this.bgColor='#E99E3E'"*

```
                        <?php elseif($result["Status"]== 'PENDING'): ?>style= "background-color:#DB7093; "
                            <?php endif; ?> >
                <!-- <td><?php echo $result["Roll_No"];?></td> -->
                <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $counter ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $result["Document_Name"];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $result["Document_Num"];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $result["Extent"];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $result["Status"];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $result["Document_App_Det"];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $result["staff_follow"];?></td>
```

Comment: I think you misspelled lightgreen, try using color code instead

Comment: Note that the PHP code has absolutely nothing to do with this. The browser only sees the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Try again with `this.bgColor='LightGreen'`.

The named colors can be found here:
https://htmlcolorcodes.com/color-names/